# Is there a way to get the IP address from the interface name, in Linux, without relying on ioctl or getifaddrs?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, ip

I need to get the IP address of a certain Linux interface, programmatically and using C, given its name.

I know that I can do this by relying on `ioctl`, like in the following code snippet:

```
struct ifreq ifreq;
struct in_addr ifIP;
int dummysfd;

dummysfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

// devname is a char* containing my interface name
strncpy(ifreq.ifr_name,devname,IFNAMSIZ);
ifreq.ifr_addr.sa_family=AF_INET;
if(ioctl(dummysfd,SIOCGIFADDR,&ifreq)!=-1) {
    ifIP=((struct sockaddr_in*)&ifreq.ifr_addr)->sin_addr;
} else {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: cannot retrieve IP address for interface %s.\n",devname);
}

close(dummysfd);
```

This solution, even though it works correctly, has the drawback of requiring the creation of a dummy socket, just to get the IP address.

My doubt is whether another method exists to get the IP address directly from the interface name without, for instance, scanning all the available interfaces (as it would be when using `getifaddrs`) and without relying on a method which requires opening a dummy socket to be passed to `ioctl`.

Does a function like `if_nametoindex()` (defined in `<net/if.h>`) exist, but which returns the IP address instead of the index?

Comment: There is netlink, which requires you to create a non-dummy socket. Does that count?

Comment: By the way, if_nametoindex is not a system call. It opens a dummy socket and does an ioctl.

Comment: @user253751 Oh, you are right! I did not delve into the actual implementation of if_nametoindex, but it seem to actually do the same, i.e. use ioctl and a dummy socket. Yes, netlink could be an interesting solution, even though I need to understand a bit more how to achieve the desired result using it, as I wasn't able to find much documentation.

Comment: @es483 They are documented in the rtnetlink(7) manpage. You can look also at the source code of [ip address](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/tree/ip/ipaddress.c) and [ip monitor](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/tree/ip/ipmonitor.c) for an example. The great advantage of rtnetlink is that you can monitor / listen for changes.

Comment: @mosvy Thank you very much for your suggestions. I will surely have a look at that manpage and at the source code of ip address, in order to try to write some C code able to retrieve the source IP address of an interface given its name, without using ioctl.